# CSRF tokens in file that we can upload a file

Tags: php, csrf, token

I am dealing with a website vulnerable to CSRF. Let's say that the page (upload.php) has the following code

```
if (isset($file_submit)) {
      //submit_file()
 }
 else {
     show_submission_form()
   }


 submission_form()
 {
     $tool_content .= <<<cData
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return 
     checkForm(this)">
     <br />
     <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th class="left">${langWorkFile}:</th>
        <td><input type="file" name="userfile" class="FormData_InputText" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th class="left">${m['comments']}:</th>
        <td><textarea name="stud_comments" rows="5" cols="55" class="FormData_InputText"> 
        </textarea></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <td><input type="submit" value="${langSubmit}" name="file_submit" /><br 
        />$langNotice3</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     <br/>
     </form>
cData;
 }
```

In order to protect it I should use CSRF tokens and so I have change the code into this:

```
  if (isset($submit)) {
      if ($_REQUEST['token_form'] != $_SESSION['token']) {
        die;
      }
      //submit_file()
 }
 else {
     show_submission_form()
   }


 submission_form()
 {
     $tool_content .= <<<cData
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return 
     checkForm(this)">
     <br />
     <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th class="left">${langWorkFile}:</th>
        <td><input type="file" name="userfile" class="FormData_InputText" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th class="left">${m['comments']}:</th>
        <td><textarea name="stud_comments" rows="5" cols="55" class="FormData_InputText"> 
        </textarea></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <td><input type="submit" value="${langSubmit}" name="file_submit" /><br 
        />$langNotice3</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     <br/>
     </form>
cData;
$tool_content .= "<td><input class='FormData_InputText' type=\"text\" size=\"40\" name=\"token_form\" value=\"$_SESSION['token']\"></td>";
 }
```

In simpler words I have added

```
  if ($_REQUEST['token_form'] != $_SESSION['token']) {
    die;
  }
```

and

```
$tool_content .= "<td><input class='FormData_InputText' type=\"text\" size=\"40\" name=\"token_form\" value=\"$_SESSION['token']\"></td>";
```

at the end.

This creates a form that its value is the token (I will make it hidden) and when the user presses submits the token is supposed to be send. However, `if ($_REQUEST['token_form'] != $_SESSION['token'])` seems to be true and so I can't achieve my goal. Do you have ideas why and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `<input />` should be inside the `<form></form>`.

As the `<input name="token_form" />` is currently outside the `<form></form>`, the token is not sent when you submit the form.

Comment: seems like it should be type='hidden', too.. and should check cookie + hidden field against session var?